# Potential obstacles to growing nanoelectronics within living cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, electrophysiology, implantation

Say there was a nanotechnology allowing to "grow" and wire up electronic components/sensors measured only a few nanometers in cross-section, though spanning in length across microns. Say this was possible inside living cells (for the purpose of monitoring or even controlling living tissues at individual cell level).

Would such a technology be doomed in the bud simply because cells will immediately deploy antibodies to fight the foreign objects off, and either succeed in it (rendering the growing of said components impossible) or die if they can't succeed in it? Or are there chances to get the cells ignore the electronic components and live with them happily?

What are any other potential obstacles to this sort of technology from biological perspective?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question because it is asking about a hypothetical situation. From the [help/dont-ask], *`avoid asking subjective questions where […] you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”`* We expect answers to be based on verifiable facts and references, along with subject-related expertise.

Comment: @MattDMo I am actually seeking facts and references, obviously not in relation to nanoelectronics in cells (unless such things exist) but in relation to implantation of foreign objects in cells in general (which, hopefully, is already not hypothetical). The reference to nanoelectronics is more of an indication of where the question is coming from rather than requirement for answers to reference it.

Comment: This question is still hypothetical, because to my knowledge no one has implanted materials of the type you're describing into animals (which you need in order to elicit an immune response. The devil is in the details here, and we simply don't have the information necessary to answer this question in anything other than a hypothetical manner... which is off-topic.

Comment: @MattDMo An answer along the lines "no one has done anything like that yet so the science does not know the answer as of today" would be a good answer then. When the time comes, it would be updated accordingly.

Comment: I think this is a really timely and interesting question. [Here is a link](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/electricity-carrying-bacteria-lead-to-new-applications-and-new-questions/) to the online version of an article that appeared in *Sci Am* last month. It may be of interest to you and shows that nanotechnology is advancing pretty rapidly in this arena. Perhaps it can help you to narrow down your question and to rewrite it into an answerable format.